# CYK - finding the closest word accepted

Tags: context-free, parsers, normal-forms

Let's say I have a context-free grammar G and a string S. The normal CYK algorithm outputs that s can not be build using G. How would I find the closest String S' that can be build using G?

Comment: You will have to define *closest*. (For "parser generators", support for error handling is for reports more often than for (suggestions for) fixes. I marvelled at the Waterloo compilers in the early 80s.)

Comment: CYK is essentially dynamic programming. Use your dynamic programming skills.

Comment: Changing or deleting a character in S costs 1. Now I'm looking for S' that costs the least but can be build from G. @YuvalFilmus if I would know how to do it I wouldn't have asked so at least some help would be nice. I know how CYK works but not how to derive the word or the number of errors in the given word.

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/tags/dynamic-programming/info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem has been solved by Myers, [Approximately Matching Context-Free Languages](https://www.cs.arizona.edu/sites/default/files/TR94-22.pdf). A more recent algorithm, together with many relevant pointers, is Rajasekaran and Nicolae, [An error correcting parser for context free grammars that takes less than cubic time](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1406.3405.pdf).